# Query a database filtered by array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table customer in my database:

Customer
  Id_customer
  name
  surname
  ...

And an array of id_customers:

```
$c = array[2,4,8,9]
```

I can obtain the customers like this:

```
$customers = Customer::all();
```

But, how can I obtain in Laravel just the customer contained in the array?

```
 $customers = Customer::all()->where(?¿?¿);
```

Very thanks in advance

Comment: `Customer::whereIn('Id_customer',$c)->get()`

Comment: This would be correct? Customer::whereIn('Id_customer',$request)->get(). Where $request is an array of id's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `whereIn()` method.

```
$users = Customer::whereIn('Id_customer', [1, 2, 3])
             ->get();
```

Read the docs on this here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Can I change [1,2,3] for $request (Being $request an array of id customers)?

Comment: Yes you can, you can replace it with whatever as long as it is an array of integers (you can use `$c` from your original question too). Although are you sure this `$request` variable is really an array?

Comment: Just its s example. I will use $customers. Where $customers = $request->all();  Very thanks!

Comment: Be aware your `$request->all()` is probably an array containing your customer_id array. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input